# android 6.0 run time permission in android?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

For android 6.0 version i added run time permissions  for android 6.0. But if the user denied the permission means my application crashing. I attached my code below. So any one help me out. Thank you in advance.

my code:

```
 private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS={
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,

            Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,

            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
    };
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ){


            if (!canAccessLocation() || !canAccessLocation_1() || !canAccessPhone() || !canAccessContacts() || !canAccessStorage() || !canAccessContacts1()
                    || !canAccessSms() || !canAccessSms1() || !canAccessSms2() || !canAccessCamera()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {


            //not a marshamallow
        }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {


        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (canAccessCamera()) {
                    doCameraThing();
                }
                else {
                    bzzzt();
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_CONTACTS:
                if (canAccessContacts()&&canAccessContacts1()) {
                    doContactsThing();
                }
                else {
                    bzzzt();
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                if (canAccessLocation()&&canAccessLocation_1()) {
                    doLocationThing();
                }
                else {
                    bzzzt();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_PHONE:
                if (canAccessPhone()) {
                    dophoneThing();
                }
                else {
                    bzzzt();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_SMS:
                if (canAccessSms()&&canAccessSms1() && canAccessSms2()) {
                    doSmsThing();
                }
                else {
                    bzzzt();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_STORAGE:
                if (canAccessStorage()) {
                    dostorageThing();
                }
                else {
                    bzzzt();
                }
                break;
        }
        checking();

    }

//location

    private boolean canAccessLocation() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
    }
    private boolean canAccessLocation_1() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION));
    }



    //phone
    private boolean canAccessPhone() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE));
    }
    private boolean canAccessStorage() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
    }


    //sms
    private boolean canAccessSms() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS));
    }
    private boolean canAccessSms1() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS));
    }
    private boolean canAccessSms2() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS));
    }


    //camera
    private boolean canAccessCamera() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA));
    }

    //contact

    private boolean canAccessContacts() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS));
    }
    private boolean canAccessContacts1() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS));
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
        return(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm)==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void bzzzt() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_bzzzt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void doCameraThing() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void doContactsThing() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_contacts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void doLocationThing() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private void doSmsThing() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_sms, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void dostorageThing() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_storage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void dophoneThing() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    //checking

    public void checking(){

        if (!m_sharedPreference.contains("useruid") && flag == true  ) {

            db.ClearTables();
            executeCircleAndOperatorsList();
        }
        else if (m_sharedPreference.contains("useruid") && flag == true  && CHECKDB == false) {

            db.ClearTables();
            executeCircleAndOperatorsList();
        }else if (m_sharedPreference.contains("useruid") && flag == true && CHECKDB == true) {

            servicemodifyremainder();
        } else if (m_sharedPreference.contains("useruid") && CHECKDB == true && flag == false) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int permissions_All = 1;
    String[] Permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, 
    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS 
     };
    if (!hasPermissions(this, Permissions)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Permissions, permissions_All);
    }
}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... Permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Permissions != null) {
        for (String Permission : Permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Write all this code in onCreate method of your activity and
Mention all permissions in manifest file and mention them in the string array